# Problems with JavaConfig for Spring MVC and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I have configured a spring MVC project using this guide:

http://javahash.com/spring-4-mvc-hello-world-tutorial-full-example/

meaning that I no longer have a **servlet xml** or the **web.xml** files in my project.

I build the project using maven and it build successfully. But in eclipse I get this error:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.MarkedException: Unable to configure webapp-module
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.AbstractProjectConfiguratorDelegate.configureProject(AbstractProjectConfiguratorDelegate.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.WTPProjectConfigurator.configure(WTPProjectConfigurator.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1351)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modifyInternal(FacetedProject.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChangesInternal(FacetedProject.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.access$2(FacetedProject.java:1117)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$1.run(FacetedProject.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2241)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modify(FacetedProject.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.WebProjectConfiguratorDelegate.configure(WebProjectConfiguratorDelegate.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.AbstractProjectConfiguratorDelegate.configureProject(AbstractProjectConfiguratorDelegate.java:94)
```

but it does not really help me much, what does:

```
One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
```

mean? I don't see any files that are red only a red cross on the project itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring java compiler in maven:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Fixed the problem in eclipse.

I next got a runtime error but fixed it by adding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Fixed the problem in eclipse